# ASP Button not firing the CLICK function inside a table generated in code behind and place in a placeholder control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have had an issue that is causing me problems.

I have an ASP Button not firing the CLICK function but it is inside a table generated in code behind and placed in a placeholder control in the html.

The table generates. The button is on screen. I click it nothing happens.

I tried several methods from writing this:

`html.Append("<asp:LinkButton id=\"" + clist[i] + "\" runat=\"server\" onClick=\"Show_Click\">" + clist[i] + "<asp:LinkButton>");`

the above didn't work as I stated then I tried:

```
 newbutton.ID = "id"; 
 newbutton.Text = "TEXT";`
 newbutton.Click += new EventHandler(Show_Click);
 newbutton.CssClass = "ButtonAsLink";
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
 HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
 newbutton.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
 html.Append(sb.ToString());
```

Again these generate the table...and the button is on screen. You can click it but it doesn't call the `CLICK` function.

I feel theres something with controls being reset or instanced but I am not sure what could I get any advice please regarding how to create a asp button, place it in a table generated in code behind, add to a placeholder control in html page ?

Comment: You can't write ASP.NET code to the output, because the output is the output of ASP.NET.  In other words, there is a parser that processes the input ASP.NET and outputs HTML (without ASP.NET code), you're trying to push ASP.NET code to the HTML output, which means the ASP.NET parser will never see it.  If you want to add a control dynamically to your page, you create the control and add it to the controls collection prior to rendering.

Comment: Take a look at my answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co/42567762#42567762). It shows how to create a Dynamic button and add it to the page.