# Dynamic Text Box Add on button click and data session in asp.net

Tags: c#, dynamic, textbox, viewstate

**QUESTION UPDATE**

I am using this piece of code for cor adding multiple labels on button click.
But each and every time it gives count value 0 and after execution only same label comes.

```
 int count = (int)ViewState["count"];
        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtnew = new TextBox();
            txtnew.ID = "label_" + (i + 1);
            txtnew.Text = "label_" + (i + 1);
            ViewState["count"] = i;
            pnlControl.Controls.Add(txtnew);
        }
 ViewState["count"] = count + 1;
```

What i want now is how to keep that data of each control binded to it in its more convenient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic controls are lost on every PostBack, so you need to keep track of the created ones somewhere and recreate them when the page is reloaded.

See my anwer here: [How to dynamically create ASP.net controls within dynamically created ASP.net controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co)

It is about buttons but the basic principle is the same. Just replace Button with Label and it will work.

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: It made it work but i have lost the previous control.

Comment: Then you are probably not storing that one in the session/viewstate.

Comment: Yup thanks i have got my answer . thanks for help and please vote up.

Answer (score 1):

That's cause it's a web application and thus the session is not retained cause web applications are stateless in nature. So, every post back you get a new page instance which will have `int count` is `0`. Solution: Use `Session` to store the data for future re-use like

```
int count = pnlControl.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
Session["count"] = count;
```

Retrieve it back on postback request

```
if(Session["count"] != null)
  count = (int)Session["count"];
```

Comment: okay let me try this. and please vote up for better response.

Comment: Yes @rahul it did but also replaced the previous label.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)