# Looping Through a Dynamic Table and extract cell values c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a dynamic table with X amount of rows and 2 columns. This is being stored in the view state.

How can I get the values of each cell per row?
Please see my code example:

```html
<p>How many rows?<asp:TextBox ID="txtNoSitesDeployed" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  onclick="Button1_Click" /></p>
    <asp:Table ID="dt" runat="server">
    </asp:Table>
    
    <asp:Button ID="btnGenerateEmail" runat="server" Text="Generate Email Content Bulk" onclick="btnGenerateEmail_Click" />
    
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTemplate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </p>
```

Please see code-behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
 protected int Rows
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["Rows"] != null ? (int)ViewState["Rows"] : 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Rows"] = value;
    }
}

protected int Columns
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["Columns"] != null ? (int)ViewState["Columns"] : 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Columns"] = value;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.Rows = Int32.Parse(txtNoSitesDeployed.Text);
        this.Columns = 2;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Total number of rows.
    int rowCnt;
    // Current row count.
    int rowCtr;
    // Total number of cells per row (columns).
    int cellCtr;
    // Current cell counter.
    int cellCnt;


    rowCnt = Rows;

    for(rowCtr=1; rowCtr <= rowCnt; rowCtr++) 
    {
        // Create a new row and add it to the table.
        TableRow row = new TableRow();

        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        var txtSiteName = new TextBox();
        txtSiteName.ID = "txtSiteName-" + rowCtr;
        txtSiteName.ToolTip = "Enter site name";
        cell1.Controls.Add(txtSiteName);

        //add cell to row
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);

        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        var ddltBU = new DropDownList();
        ddltBU.ID = "ddltBU-" + rowCtr;
        ddltBU.Items.Add(new ListItem("fruit", "fruit"));
        cell2.Controls.Add(ddltBU);

        //add cell to row
        row.Cells.Add(cell2);

        //add row to dt
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

protected void btnGenerateEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(TableRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach(TableCell cell in dt.Rows)
        {
            Response.Write(cell.Text);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I can't seem to access the cell values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to keep track of the number of rows and recreate them on every PostBack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create ASP.net controls within dynamically created ASP.net controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co)