# How to retain dynamically created control after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm working on a quiz web app in ASP.Net C#. In the editquiz page, it allows user to add and remove questions from the quiz using JS. Once user have saved the changes, question data will be passed from client to server for validation before storing in db. If the string fails validation, it will alert the user however, the question controls constructed previously will be destroyed upon postback.

How can I retain the question controls and their values apart from reconstructing them based on the posted JSON string?

Comment: You have to keep track of the Controls created and re-create them on PostBack. For a demo see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that save or submit button inside scriptmanager of ajax controls.

Add scriptmanager tag next to  your form tag,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

and

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate >
        your button of save or submit,
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```