# Dynamically created buttons getting disappeared after clicking

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an asp.net application(framework 4.7). I am trying to create buttons dynamically depending upon the values from database. I am using master page. Inside content place holder I have written the following code:

```
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
```

In the code behind I am creating buttons dynamically on the click event of another button:

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> dbParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        dbParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", Convert.ToInt64(ddlProfile.SelectedValue)));
        dbParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProfileId", Convert.ToInt64(ddlProfile.SelectedValue)));
        dbParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClientId", "AP001C01"));
        DataTable dt = DBManager.GetDataTable("espGetServiceUserWise", dbParameters, conn);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (row["Value"].ToString() == "Accounts")
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.ID = "btnAccounts";
                btn.Text = "Accounts";
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnAccounts_Click);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
            else if(row["Value"].ToString() == "Income Tax")
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.ID = "btnIT";
                btn.Text = "Income Tax";
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnIT_Click);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is creating buttons dynamically. I have written following code on click event of the dynamically created buttons:

```
protected void btnAccounts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Accounts", "alert('Accounts!');", true);
    }

    protected void btnIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "IT", "alert('IT');", true);
    }
```

But the problem is that when I am clicking on dynamically created buttons all the buttons disappear.

Perhaps it is happening for post back. How can I fix the problem? Thanks

Partha

Comment: You are fighting the tool, the issue is occurring because the page loads, the button executes, then the button is created.  But once you click the page load fires, which does not know what the state is, so it is redefining until your next event.  This approach you have, would be better suited for a generic handler file and JavaScript.  Otherwise web forms will force a page state you are not able to handle, and if you do handle it the amount of extra code will be unmanageable.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co). You need to keep track of all the created buttons and recreate them on PostBack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create ASP.net controls within dynamically created ASP.net controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co)