# How to add dynamic controls with different ID and having a different Click event in asp.net on a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["i"] = 1;
        }
    }
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            int i = (int)ViewState["i"];
            Button MyButton = new Button();
            MyButton.ID = "MyButton" + i;
            divContainer.Controls.Add(MyButton);

            i++;
            ViewState["i"] = i;
         }
```

Whenever i click on button to add a new control in a div with id="descriptionBox", then last created control gets deleted from that div and new control gets created instead.I want to create a new control on every click And add them into that div.

Comment: You increment `i`, but never add more that one control. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Asp controls, it renders at server side 
every time you add control it refreshes the page and previous content goes away 
you can use `Page_PreInit` event

```
 protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
           Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key.Contains("button name")).ToList();
 }
```

event to retain or re-Create the existing control
for more information have a look on the link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Dynamic-Controls-ViewState-Retain-state-for-dynamically-created-controls-on-PostBack.aspx