# Dynamic buttons not functioning when clicked c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I am trying to create a form where dynamic buttons will appear after specifying the number of iterations. In this case, I used a table to store the buttons.

```
//my n is declared globally
  n = int.Parse(txtQNo.Text);


        Button[] addQuestion = new Button[n];
        Button[] getFromDatabase = new Button[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            addQuestion[i] = new Button();
            getFromDatabase[i] = new Button();

            addQuestion[i].Text = "Add a new question";
            getFromDatabase[i].Text = "Get one from database";
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(addQuestion[i]);
        cell.Controls.Add(getFromDatabase[i]);

        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        tabQuestions.Rows.Add(row);
```

The problem comes when I try to associate the dynamic buttons with a on_click function. My on_click functions are like this:

```
protected void btnAddQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button) sender;
            Response.Redirect("~/SomeWebPage.aspx");
    }
       protected void btnGetFromData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Button btn = (Button) sender;
        Response.Redirect("~/SomeOtherWebPage.aspx"); 
    }
```

I tried doing this:

```
addQuestion[i].Click += btnAddQuestion_Click;
        getFromDatabase[i].Click += btnGetFromData_Click;
```

When I run my code, and I fire the function to create the buttons, the buttons will appear, but once I click on them they just disappear.

Any help will be appreciated :) Been stuck here for a few hours already :(

If my language is not standard forgive me I'm still quite new to programming.

If you need any other info just tell me :)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a very good description. Maybe you want to tell us what it does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I need the dynamic buttons to direct to the web pages shown in the last part of the code. Unfortunately the buttons just disappeared when I clicked on them.

Comment: "just disappeared" is a very useful information. Well, you redirect to some other page. Why should the button be on that page? You created it on this page, right?

Comment: I think you mistaken my point here. This entire function fires after I clicked a button, in order to display the dynamic buttons, based on the number of iterations i requested. So, all buttons mentioned here belong to the same page. The button should redirect to the web page specified, not appear at some other web page.

Comment: I mean the dynamic button when clicked should redirect the user to another web page.

Comment: You need to keep track of all the buttons and recreate them on PostBack. See my answer for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Comment: @VDWWD Thank you! I managed to solve this, from the link you given, gotta thank the person who had posted the question too!