# Asp.net: Response.Write OnServerClick codebehind function not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make it so if your `Session["LoggedIn"]` is true, the wuc (**Web User Control**, which is the **Navbar** and is connected to the **MasterPage** which is connected to the page) prints a `logout` button.

so I have it like this:

```
Response.Write("<a runat='server' ID='lblLogout' class='nav-link' CausesValidation='False' OnServerClick='lblLogout_Click'>Logout</a>");
```

the CodeBehind function looks like this:

```
protected void lblLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Session["LoggedIn"] = false;
    Session["IsAdmin"] = false;
    Session["Username"] = "";

}
```

now, I've tried everything, if I use `response.write` like that, I can't click it, it just doesn't fire or do anything, if I don't use it inside Response.Write, it does work..
I even tried prinitng an `asp:LinkButton` instead to see if that works, but it doesn't print out anything when I use it like:

```
Response.Write("<asp:LinkButton class='nav-link' runat='server' ID='lblLogout' Text='Logout' CausesValidation='False' OnClick='lblLogout_Click' />");
```

Now the solution that I found was putting another page for logout and placing the function on `PageLoad`, which works, but I'm wondering if I can make it work so I can use the function from CodeBehind, instead of having to go to another page.
my working solution:

```
if ((bool)Session["LoggedIn"] == true)
             {
                 Response.Write("<li class='nav-item'> <a runat='server' ID='lblLogout' class='nav-link' CausesValidation='False' href='../PagesForVisitor/wfLogout.aspx'>Logout</a></li><li><a class='navbar-brand' href='#'><img src='" + GetSource() + "' width = '30' height = '30' alt = ''/ ></a></li>");
             }
```

(this one prints out a profile pic as well)

p.s using `Bootstrap` for styling, not sure if that matters, thanks a bunch..

Comment: You cannot add `runat=server` as a string and expect it to work. You need to add "real" controls.

Comment: `<a runat='server' ...>` inside `Response.Write` will not work. You need to use `LiteralControl` or `HtmlControl` for rendering anchor link with server-side capability.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Got any tips on how to implement that?

Comment: @VDWWD how exactly do I add "real" controls??

Comment: See this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<asp:Button id='' runat='server'>
```

tag
or use css to custom the button look depending on the style.

You can make it a hyperlink in the properties.