# I get an error when creating imagebutton for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

imagebutton do[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1asGy.png)es not appear sequentially when I create it I believe the code is correct where is the error

```
 Button1.text=Button1.text+1
  Dim btn As ImageButton = New ImageButton
    btn.Height = "64"
    btn.Width = "64"
    btn.ImageAlign = ImageAlign.Baseline
    btn.ID = "image" & Button1.Text
        btn.CssClass = "position: page;left:" & (Button1.Text) * 64 & "px;top: 0px;"
    btn.ImageUrl = "~/image/Apps-sylpheed-icon.png"
    Panel1.Controls.Add(btn)
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf tıkla
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Comment: If you get an error, it makes sense to tell us what the error is. It's not easy for us to guess

Comment: I will try ....

Comment: thanks I figured out the other way