# Dynamic Button's Event Handler Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, what I have here is 2 things. I have a static Button called MainButton that is already there permanently. What MainButton does is that it creates a dropdownlist and another button (setButton) dynamically. However when I create a onclickevent for setButton it does not seem to fire. I have seen several examples of this question and realised that I have to use Page_Init method for it to work, but I have no idea to implement this in my code and I really need help. (Sorry I am just a beginner at ASP.NET)

Here's my code :

---

```
public partial class createTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{


  public DropDownList questionType = new DropDownList();
  string selectedQuestion;



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected  void Page_OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void setButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("Test");


    }

    protected void mainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ContentPlaceHolder mainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

        questionType.Items.Add("MCQ");
        questionType.Items.Add("Open Ended");
        mainContent.Controls.Add(questionType);


        Create();
        selectedQuestion = questionType.SelectedValue;
        Debug.WriteLine(selectedQuestion);


    }

    void Create ()
    {
            ContentPlaceHolder mainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
            Button setBtn;

            setBtn = new Button();
            setBtn.Text = "Set";
            setBtn.Click += new EventHandler(setButton_Click);
            mainContent.Controls.Add(setBtn);

    }
}
```

}

---

Comment: You have to keep track of dynamic controls and recreate them on postback. See my answer for a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Comment: @VDWWD how do i use your example in the context of my code

Comment: You have to execute `Create()` every time the page loads

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the postback, 
dynamic button and asp.net dosn't work good together.
I prefer adding the button and set it on visible="false" and set it to "true" on the click.

if you have multi buttons to add you can use repeater.

Comment: They work just fine together. If you know how to use them.

Comment: yes, but i think that the way it work is not friendly.
look at this for example: https://forums.asp.net/t/1959701.aspx?Dynamically+added+event+handler+not+firing+

Comment: With the nature of how im designing this application, it does not permit me to use visibility property to manage this :(