# Creating Dynamic button C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, controls

i'm working in ASP.NET in visual studio.
I tried to dynamicly create a list of buttons in C# and make its appears on an update panel, and it worked.

My problem is the following : i've created this list with a for loop and so, every buttons has the same OnClick method. So, when i click on one of its, it doesn't do anything.
Do you have any ideas of what my problem can be ?
this is my for loop for creating :

```
for (int i = 1; i < eq.Count; i += 3)
{
    Button nom = new Button();
    nom.Text = "btn-"+ Convert.ToString(i);
    nom.ID = ("Nom" + i).ToString();
    nom.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Agent_Click);
    Panel.Controls.Add(nom);

    Button refurl = new Button();
    refurl.Text = equipes[i + 2];
    refurl.ID = ("refURL" + i).ToString();

    indice++;
}
```

Have a great day ! :)

Comment: Are you able to debug the code `btn_Agent_Click` method when click on a button?

Comment: hi Chetan, no i can't, it kind of "skips" the line "nom.Click +=..."

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Comment: what  code is available on  btn_Agent_Click? and share complete code of load event...

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved creating dynamic buttons using the following code for click event

```
nom.Click += (s, e) => {
    // add your logic here for each button where s,e are (object sender, EventArgs e)
};
```

Hope it helps!