# Dynamic Button On Click Event Not Firing

Tags: html, asp.net, dynamic

I am having trouble with getting the onclick event to fire when I click the button. I can see the button on the page just fine, but the action is never getting called. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it

```
// This is adding it to my existing table and trying to generate the button with the on click event
// I am looping through a list of users and trying to add an activate button for each of them                    
If mycount < 3 Then
 litExpiredUser.Text += "<td><input type='button' onclick='btnActivate' name='Activate' value='Activate' id='btnActivate(" & USERID & ")' class='activateButton' title='Activate'></td>"
End If
```

```
    Protected Sub btnActivate_Click(UserID)
{
    // Performing My Activation work
    // When done Calling Page Refresh to show new activations

}
```

```
// This is where I call the control to show my table on the page
<asp:Literal ID="litExpiredAccess" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Comment: You need to create actual aspnet buttons, not buttons as html, like `Button button = new Button();`. See example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with input button an javascriot fun

```
<td><input type='button' onclick='btnActivate()' name='Activate' value='Activate' id='btnActivate(" & USERID & ")' class='activateButton' title='Activate'></td>
 ....
 
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function btnActivate() {
        //....
        }
   </script>
```