# Add control (with server side event handler) and it's parent container dynamically ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to add a component dynamically, that is essentially a container with two buttons in. I need the buttons to postback and fire a server side method. So far I've tried using 'HtmlButton mybtn = new HtmlButton()', but because I need to add the button's parent container dynamically at the same time it can't find the container to add it to. So I've resorted to adding the component as concatenating html. I don't think I'm able to use PageMethods as the methods I need the buttons to call need to post a response so can't be static. The closest I've come is below, but the method isn't firing. I have tried both with 'type="button"' and without. Any help on a way round the issue would be much appreciated.

```
doccarousel.InnerHtml +=
                        "<div class=\"documentdropdown\" id=\"dropdown" + filenamepart + "\">" +
                            "<button runat=\"server\" type=\"button\" class=\"txt2 link dropdownbtn\" id=\"download" + filenamepart + "\" onserverclick=\"downloadblobfile\" fileuri=\"" + fileuri + "\" >" +
                            "<i class=\"fad fa-trash fa-1x fontawesome-style deleteicon dropdownicon\"></i>download" +
                            "</button> </br>" +
                            "<button runat=\"server\" class=\"txt2 link dropdownbtn\" id=\"delete" + filenamepart + "\" onserverclick=\"deletefile\" fileuri=\"" + fileuri + "\" >" +
                            "<i class=\"fad fa-file fa-1x download fontawesome-style documenticon dropdownicon\"></i>delete" +
                            "</button>" +
                        "</div>";
```

```
        public void downloadblobfile()
        {
            Response.Write("download button clicked");
            // Download Blob and push to client

        }
```

Comment: You cannot add `runat=\"server\" to a string and expect to create asp controls. You need REAL dynamic controls. See example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks for your response. This was my initial approach, but requires you to have a previously created container to add the control to. I need to create the container in the same event.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work. You need to add that container also to something on the page. But an empty PlaceHolder on the page can be used for adding controls.