# Problem second click create dynamically elements ASP.NET WEB FORMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, webforms

It does not create the button dynamically when I click the button a second time. It only creates the button on the first click and then not. What could it be?

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    static bool enable = false;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
    }

    protected void btnAgregarItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = "HOLA";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}


<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ejemplo._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<div class="container">
<asp:Button ID="btnAgregarItems" runat="server" Text="Agregar Items" CssClass="btn btn-primary my-3" OnClick="btnAgregarItems_Click" />
<div class="row">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAgregarItems" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

```
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: you're probably doing a post-back...

Comment: You might want to debug the code and see the value of `PlaceHolder1.Controls.Count` at runtime while clicking on for 2nd and 3rd time. It might happen that the button is created but hiding behind the first button..

Comment: You have to keep track of all the created controls and recreate them on page_load: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co