# Adding javascript var value into string

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have dynamically added textbox in asp.net web form page using javascript as following

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = "Placehoder";
    $("#partAdder").click(function () {
        newPart =
            '<div class="row" id="row">' +
            '<div class="col-xl-2">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder='+i+' />' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        $('#newistrpart').append(newPart);
     });
```

How to pass the i value to the script "using that script i gent +i+ instead of the value"

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate what specifically isn't working as expected in that example?  As an aside... `runat="server"` is not a client-side HTML attribute and will do absolutely nothing here.  Given the `asp.net` tag, you may be confusing the difference between client-side code and server-side code.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make much sense, what's the issue with the code?

Comment: As @David says, if you want to use those input fields in code behind on PostBack, you need to add 'real' aspnet webform controls dynamically. Not as string values. Or put them in a GridView, Repeater etc.

Comment: For what it's worth, [your code demonstrably works as-is](https://jsfiddle.net/0wzpqj46/), so it's difficult for us to *guess* what problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: thnks @David the script actually works i just have to remove runat="server"

Comment: @VDWWD could you explain how to add 'real' aspnet webform controls dynamically

Comment: See an example of mine here, this is about buttons, but the principle is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Answer (score 1):

you can use string interpolation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = "Placehoder";
$("#partAdder").click(function () {
    newPart = `<div class="row" id="row">
        <div class="col-xl-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="${i}" /> // <-- update this line
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;
    $('#newistrpart').append(newPart);
});
</script>
```

${i} syntax is used to include the value of the i variable within the string. The backticks (`) are used to enclose the string, which allows for string interpolation.

backtick shortcut on Windows is Alt + 96

you can use string concatenation to achieve the same result, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = "Placehoder";
$("#partAdder").click(function () {
    newPart = '<div class="row" id="row">' +
        '<div class="col-xl-2">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
                '<input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="' + i + '" />' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';
    $('#newistrpart').append(newPart);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok now I update my answer using concatenation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if I understand your JS code, you forgot to put " on your placeholder like that`'<input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="'+i+'" />'`