# Linkbutton in ASP.NET does not have onclick event on backend

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to dynamically create a list of link buttons. I need the link buttons to have an onclick event.  When I try to add the `onclick` event in C#, I get this error:

> The name OnClick does not exist in the current context.

This is my code:

```
protected void fillList()
{
    List<PdfInfo> pdf = new List<PdfInfo>();
    pdf.Add(new PdfInfo { Path =  @"c:\TestCode\TestPdfs\", PdfName = "testPdf1.pdf"  });
    pdf.Add(new PdfInfo { Path = @"c:\TestCode\TestPdfs\", PdfName = "testPdf1.pdf" });
    pdf.Add(new PdfInfo { Path = @"c:\TestCode\TestPdfs\", PdfName = "testPdf1.pdf" });

    List<LinkButton> x = new List<LinkButton>();

    foreach(PdfInfo i in pdf)
    {
        x.Add(new LinkButton { ID = i.PdfName, Text = i.PdfName, OnClientClick = "linkBtnNewTab();", OnClick +="" });
    }
}
```

Is there no way to add an `onclick` event handler dynamically?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567762/5836671. But you cannot add it in the same way as a property.

Comment: Why do you think you need an `<asp:LinkButton>` instead of a HTML-only `<a href=#"">`? Consider that using your approach means that users won't be able to middle-click the link to open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this approach can dynamically create LinkButton controls with an `OnClick` event handler in your code

```
protected void fillList()
{
    List<PdfInfo> pdf = new List<PdfInfo>();
    pdf.Add(new PdfInfo { Path = @"c:\TestCode\TestPdfs\", PdfName = "testPdf1.pdf" });
    pdf.Add(new PdfInfo { Path = @"c:\TestCode\TestPdfs\", PdfName = "testPdf2.pdf" });
    pdf.Add(new PdfInfo { Path = @"c:\TestCode\TestPdfs\", PdfName = "testPdf3.pdf" });

    foreach (PdfInfo info in pdf)
    {
        LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton
        {
            ID = "lnk_" + info.PdfName,
            Text = info.PdfName,
            OnClientClick = "linkBtnNewTab();"
        };

        linkButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Your click event handler code here
            Response.Redirect(info.Path + info.PdfName);
        };

        // Add the LinkButton to the container (e.g., a Panel or a placeholder)
        // For example, if you have a Panel named panel1:
        panel1.Controls.Add(linkButton);
    }
}
```

Note: The `OnClick` property is not directly accessible in your context. You need to use the `Click` event instead like in the above example.