# Generate buttons for dynamically-generated HTML code

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an ASP.NET WebForms application and I'm dynamically generating the HTML code for [this Bootstrap timeline](https://www.codeply.com/p/GSinLfFXIJ) based on the results of a SQL query. I'd like to add *delete* and *modify* buttons to each entry, so that the corresponding modals open and the user can change the contents. How can I do that?

I've tried generating a simple HTML button (with the same ID) and running it on the server, but it doesn't work:

```html
<button id="myButton" runat="server" onclick="myButton_Click()">Delete</button>
```

EDIT: I already have the logic to modify and delete, I just don't know how to do that for the HTML code generated at runtime.

Comment: Webforms does not work that way, you cannot add a server click in html. You need dynamic controls for that. See my answer here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567762/5836671

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To dynamically generate delete and modify buttons for each entry in your Bootstrap timeline and handle their click events in an ASP.NET WebForms application, you'll need to make a few modifications to your code.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

**1. Generate Buttons Dynamically in Code-Behind:**
In your server-side code-behind file (e.g., .aspx.cs), you can dynamically generate buttons for each timeline entry and handle their click events. You need to make sure that these buttons are created during the Page_Load event and that their click events are associated with corresponding methods.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Assume dt is a DataTable containing your SQL query results
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            // Dynamically create a button for delete
            Button deleteButton = new Button();
            deleteButton.ID = "deleteButton_" + row["EntryID"]; // Use a unique ID for each button
            deleteButton.Text = "Delete";
            deleteButton.CssClass = "btn btn-danger";
            deleteButton.Click += new EventHandler(DeleteButton_Click);

            // Dynamically create a button for modify
            Button modifyButton = new Button();
            modifyButton.ID = "modifyButton_" + row["EntryID"]; // Use a unique ID for each button
            modifyButton.Text = "Modify";
            modifyButton.CssClass = "btn btn-warning";
            modifyButton.Click += new EventHandler(ModifyButton_Click);

            // Add buttons to the corresponding timeline entry
            // You may need to find the parent container based on your HTML structure
            // and add buttons to that container
            // For example, assuming you have a div with the ID "timelineContainer"
            // you can find it and add buttons like this:
            HtmlGenericControl timelineContainer = FindControl("timelineContainer") as HtmlGenericControl;
            if (timelineContainer != null)
            {
                timelineContainer.Controls.Add(deleteButton);
                timelineContainer.Controls.Add(modifyButton);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Event handler for delete button click
protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Handle delete logic here
}

// Event handler for modify button click
protected void ModifyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Handle modify logic here
}
```

**2. Modify HTML to Display Buttons:**
Update your HTML structure to include a container (e.g., a Panel) where the dynamically generated buttons will be added.

```
<div class="container py-4" runat="server" id="timelineContainer">
    <!-- Your existing timeline HTML goes here -->
</div>
```

Ensure that the runat="server" attribute is added to the container so that it can be accessed in the code-behind.

By following these steps, you should be able to dynamically generate delete and modify buttons for each entry in your Bootstrap timeline, and handle their click events on the server side. Adjust the code as needed based on your specific requirements and HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried adding the buttons to the panel as you wrote it, but the control is never found i.e. `timelineContainer` is always null (maybe it has something to do with the fact that I use a master page). But if I add it as `timelineContainer.Controls.Add(deleteButton);` it works, but the buttons appear at the bottom of the div.

Comment: You're right I updated the code. `Panel` changed to `HtmlGenericControl` in code behind. If `timelineContainer` is nested within another container in your HTML code, you should find `timelineContainer` within the controls of that specific container. For example, use `var contentPlaceHolder = FindControl("MainContent") as HtmlGenericControl`, and then find it within that using `contentPlaceHolder.FindControl("timelineContainer") as HtmlGenericControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something in code-behind like adding the HTML dynamically using string interpolation to pass in the ID of the item:

```
<button class='btn btn-danger delete-button' data-id='{item.Id}' type='button'>Delete</button>
<button class='btn btn-primary modify-button' data-id='{item.Id}' type='button'>Modify</button>
```

...and then in JavaScript do:

```js
document.querySelector('#yourTimelineContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('delete-button')) {
        var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        __doPostBack('DeleteEntry', id);
    } else if (e.target.classList.contains('modify-button')) {
        var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        __doPostBack('ModifyEntry', id);
    }
});
```

Then in your code-behind file again, handle the custom postbacks:

```cs
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, string eventArgument)
{
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl, eventArgument);
    if (eventArgument.StartsWith("DeleteEntry"))
    {
        var id = eventArgument.Replace("DeleteEntry", "");
        DeleteEntry(id); // Your method to delete the entry
    }
    else if (eventArgument.StartsWith("ModifyEntry"))
    {
        var id = eventArgument.Replace("ModifyEntry", "");
        // Show modal or redirect to modify page with the id
        ShowModifyModal(id); // Your method to show modify modal
    }
}
```

Maybe this helps?